# C++ & WINSOCK - Recv two struct & two messages

Tags: c++, c, struct

I try to recv all data which i send.

I send this:

```
wpisano = send(maindll_socket, (char *)"witam", sizeof("witam"), 0);
wpisano2 = send(maindll_socket, (char *)"Pozdrawiam", sizeof("Pozdrawiam"), 0);
```

and recv

```
unsigned __stdcall main_pipe_server(void* Args)
{
    Sleep(500);
    LRESULT uiMessage;
    char wiadomosc[512];
    char tmpbuff[1024];
    int bytesRecv = SOCKET_ERROR;
    while (true){
        bytesRecv = recv(mainmenu::getInstance().dll_clients[0], wiadomosc, sizeof(wiadomosc), 0);
        if (bytesRecv > 0){
            MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR) wiadomosc, "DONE", NULL);
            sprintf_s(tmpbuff, 1023, "%s = %d | %d", wiadomosc, strlen(wiadomosc),bytesRecv );
            OutputDebugString(tmpbuff);
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
//(...)
}
```

And the result was -

MessageBox - "witam"

Debug: "witam = 5 | 17"

### So where is second msg?

Above was a simple question.
But i try to send two msg with data (which one was number of struct, and second is struct):

```
    int id=STRUCT_INIT_NUM;
    struct ST_ConInitChar a;
    a = { "BeCareful", python_func.py_getCurrentHp(), python_func.py_getMaxHp(), python_func.py_getMaxSp(), python_func.py_getMaxSp(), python_func.py_getMoney() };
    DWORD wpisano,wpisano2 = 0;
    wpisano = send(maindll_socket,(char *) &id, sizeof(id), 0);
    wpisano2 = send(maindll_socket, (char *)&a, sizeof(a), 0);
```

And recv - but it didn't working:

```
    unsigned __stdcall main_pipe_server(void* Args)
{
    Sleep(500);
    LRESULT uiMessage;
    char wiadomosc[512];
    char tmpbuff[1024];
    int bytesRecv = SOCKET_ERROR;
    while (true){
        bytesRecv = recv(mainmenu::getInstance().dll_clients[0], wiadomosc, sizeof(wiadomosc), 0);
        if (bytesRecv > sizeof(int)){
            char * p = wiadomosc;
            int *pId = (int*)p;
            p += sizeof(*pId);
            if (*pId == STRUCT_INIT_NUM){
                ST_ConInitChar * a = (ST_ConInitChar *)p;
                if (sizeof(a) > 0 && strlen(wiadomosc) > 0){
                    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR)a->name, (LPCSTR) "DONE", NULL); // crash my program
                }
            }
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
//(...)
}
```

Comment: When you say "msg", can you explain *precisely* what you mean? If you're expecting your receive code to receive messages, where is the code that does this? The `recv` function on a TCP connection just receives bytes from the TCP connection. It has no idea what a message is. (And, I suspect, you don't either.)

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are sending a total of 17 bytes and then reading 512 bytes.  Your `wiadomosc` buffer ends up receiving both messages.  You only see one message being displayed because you are including the null terminators in your sent data and then treating the received data as a null terminated string.  A string literal is implemented as a `const char[]` so you are effectively doing this:

```
const char str1[] = "witam"; // "witam\0"
wpisano = send(maindll_socket, (char *)str1, sizeof(str1), 0); // sizeof = 6, not 5
```

If you do not want your data to be null terminated then use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()`.

Your second example does not work because your struct's `name` member is a pointer to outside data that is not contained in the struct itself.  When you send the struct, you are sending the pointer itself, not the data that it is pointing at.  In this case, you cannot send the struct as-is, you need to serialize it into a transmittable format and send that instead, then receive it and deserialize it back into a meaningful struct.  You do not have to do that with POD types, like integers, but you do with pointers, like character strings.  I would suggest you send a string's length followed by the string's characters. That way, you can read the length first, allocate a sufficient buffer, then read the characters in to it.

Comment: Yes you have right :)

But tell me, how to distinguish first message between second message?

Now my "message" seems like "witamPozdrawiam"

Comment: Can you show an example, about second example?

My struct is [link](http://pastebin.com/BWWGMgWf)

Comment: In the first example, you need to delimit the messages. If you are just sending strings, the null terminator is fine for that. Or preceed each transmitted string with its length. In the second example, the id describes which struct is being sent, and the struct layout governs how the struct data is terminated. However, there are serialization formats that are more generic and flexible, such as TLD (type, length, data). I suggeat you adopt one.